# Measuring C# / Async Data Access Using StopWatch Class

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have the following code and it seems the Elapsed Milliseconds are inaccurate:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var connString = RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated
                                 ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Poc"].ConnectionString
                                 : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PocVm"].ConnectionString;

            var repository = new AccountRepository(connString);
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            var accounts = await repository.GetAll();

            stopWatch.Stop();
            ViewBag.Accounts = accounts;
            ViewBag.VmStatus = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            blah blah blah...
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Does this look correct or am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: It looks OK to me. Why do you conclude it's inaccurate? FYI, very short timings cannot be measured accurately using this technique; check out the `Stopwatch.Frequency` field.

Comment: Looks fine to me too. Just made a little test (https://dotnetfiddle.net/wLzfor ) to see if async fiddled with the stopwatch for some reason, but it doesn't.

Comment: (works even using `ConfigureAwait(false)`)

Answer (score 0):

this looks perfectly okay to me.

A potential error would be if the Repository.GetAll method is not async, hopefully it has a signature like so:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Account>> GetAll();
```

Comment: I don't think it'd compile without an async method signature